# Is there a summarizing term for scientific workshops, conferences, journals?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I am looking for a term that stands for all kinds of academic venues, such as workshops or conferences, or other institutions or opportunities *to which you can submit papers for review*.

An exemplary sentence is:

> These contributions have been submitted to different scientific
>   [workshops, conferences, journals, ...].

Is there a suitable term for that? I have the annoying feeling that one is sitting on the tip of my tongue.

I assume the term "scientific venues" excludes journals and is limited to workshops or conferences or other occasions where people meet in person.

Comment: Could you say "venues and publications"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately not, I think. You cannot *submit* something to a publication. You *get* a publication by submitting it somewhere and getting it accepted there.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of definition #2 here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/publication : a book, magazine, etc., that has been printed and made available to the public

Comment: I see your point :) However, I think even def. #2 doesn't fit. An article I submit to a journal is a publication in the sense of def. #2. Also a book I write on my own is my publication. But what if I submit a book chapter to a book that is edited by someone else? Talking of a publication (book chapter) submitted to a publication (book), doesn't sound good to me. This is more complicated than I thought...

Comment: No... you're submitting **to** a publication. Your article isn't a publication, **the journal is**. Publication is synonymous to journal, magazine, book, etc... See the noun tab here: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/publication

Comment: Well in scientific "slang" the article in a journal definitly is a publication. Just search for "list of publications" and you will find many web pages of scientists listing articles or book chapters as publications. I would sum that up as follows: "publication" fits in general, but is odd in the very special and narrow case I have here (academia / computer science).

Comment: Do you submit directly to a conference/institution/journal, or to a review board, council or some other group of people associated with those conferences/institutions/journals?

Comment: As far as I know, *scientific venues* is commonly employed in academia to encompass workshops, conferences and journals. Probably this usage has not yet been recorded by dictionaries, but academics should not have any problem in understanding it (disclaimer: I'm an academic, but not a native English speaker).

Comment: @ColeenV I submit directly to a conference/journal. The conference/journal then appoints a number of reviewers from its comittee.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I aggree with you on that and *venue* was what I first wrote. Then one of my colleages criticized it when proofreading my paper, but we both aren't native speakers. That is my reason for asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joergl, I would disagree with the consensus here and concur with your friend as it concerns using "venues" to summarize "events and publications".

My main objection would be that although the word '"venue" would be an appropriate synonym for both events and publications according to a dictionary, the use of "venue" in general usage is so restricted that 'scientific venues' could lead to confusion. The point of writing, even when summarizing an idea, is for clarity.

May I suggest "scientific forums"?

Comment: Thanks, "scientific forums" sounds like a good idea :) I will use the term for now. A few more people are going to read the text, so I'll see if someone objects.

Comment: Two more people (non-native speakers, alas) have read the text by now. No one objected to the term, so it is fine by me. Thanks a lot!